# How to handle data file, control fit extending with x-axis and fit logistic

Tags: gnuplot

I have a long.dat file as following.

```
#x1      y1     sd1      x2       y2    sd2      x3       y3    sd3
2.50    9.04    0.03    2.51    16.08   0.04    2.50    26.96   0.07
2.25    9.06    0.05    1.84    16.01   0.16    1.91    26.94   0.21
1.11    9.12    0.19    1.06    15.90   0.14    1.30    26.41   0.10
0.71    9.97    0.18    0.86    16.47   0.33    0.92    28.59   0.92
0.60    11.36   0.24    0.77    17.31   0.18    0.73    33.55   1.40
0.56    12.44   0.55    0.72    18.25   0.25    0.65    37.82   2.16
0.50    14.23   0.37    0.71    18.73   0.49    0.57    44.75   2.69
0.43    16.93   1.20    0.63    20.55   0.64    0.51    52.11   1.01
0.38    19.18   1.12    0.57    22.27   0.94    0.47    58.01   2.17
0.32    24.83   2.26    0.52    25.04   0.53    0.42    65.92   2.62
0.30    28.87   1.39    0.46    29.75   2.41    0.38    71.60   1.81
0.25    34.23   2.07    0.41    37.92   1.49    0.34    75.81   0.68
0.21    39.52   0.53    0.37    43.33   1.81    0.32    77.12   0.68
0.16    44.10   1.81    0.32    47.22   0.57    0.28    79.87   2.03
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.28    49.36   0.99    0.22    85.93   1.32
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.22    53.94   0.98    0.19    89.10   2.14
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.18    57.28   1.56    0.16    96.48   1.28
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.14    63.66   1.90    0.14    100.09  1.46
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.12    67.92   0.64    0.12    103.90  0.48
0.13    49.73   1.19    0.12    67.92   0.64    0.12    103.90  0.48
```

I tried to fit my data with second order polynomial. I am having problems with

(1) My x1,y1,sd1 data coluns are shorter than x2,y,sd2. So I had to append x1,y2,sd1 at x1= 0.13. Otherwise, text file is doing "something" resulting wrong plotting. Is there any way to avoid it rather than appending with same values?

[image: test.jpg]
(2) In my plotting, the fit f8(x) is extending the last value at about 7.5 to match f12(x) at about x = 8.25. If I set my x-range [0:100], all the fits extend to x=100. How can I control this?

Here are the codes,

```
Set key left
f8(x) = a8*x*x+b8*x+c8
fit f8(x) 'long.dat' u (1/$1):($2/800**3) via a8,b8,c8
plot f8(x), 'long.dat' u (1/$1):($2/800**3): ($3/800**3) w errorbars not

f10(x) = a10*x*x+b10*x+c10
fit f10(x) 'long.dat' u (1/$4):($5/1000**3) via a10,b10,c10
replot f10(x), 'long.dat' u (1/$4):($5/1000**3): ($6/1000**3) w errorbars not

f12(x) = a12*x*x+b12*x+c12
fit f12(x) 'long.dat' u (1/$7):($8/1200**3) via a12,b12,c12
replot f12(x), '' u (1/$7):($8/1200**3): ($9/1200**3) w errorbars not
```

(3) I tried to use logistic fit g(x) = a/(1+b*exp(-k*x)) on x1,y1 data set but severaly failed! Codes are here,

```
Set key left
g(x) = a/(1+b*exp(-k*x))
fit g(x) 'long.dat' u (1/$1):($2/800**3) via a,b,k
plot g(x), 'long.dat' u (1/$1):($2/800**3): ($3/800**3) w errorbars not
```

Any comment/suggestion would be highly appreciated! Many many thanks for going through this big post and any feedback in advance!

Comment: Now you have a clear and concise question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more suggestions besides @bibi's answer:

1. How should gnuplot know, that at a certain row the first number it encounters belongs to column 4? For this you can use e.g. a comma as column delimiter:

   ```
   0.16, 44.10, 1.81, 0.32, 47.22, 0.57, 0.28, 79.87, 2.03
   0.13, 49.73, 1.19, 0.28, 49.36, 0.99, 0.22, 85.93, 1.32
       ,      ,     , 0.22, 53.94, 0.98, 0.19, 89.10, 2.14
   ```

   And tell gnuplot about it:

   ```
   set datafile separator ','
   ```
2. All functions are drawn with the same xrange. You can use different limits for a function by return `1/0` when outside the desired range:

   ```
   f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
   f_p(x, min, max) = (x >= min && x <= max) ? f(x) : 1/0
   plot f_p(x, 0.5, 7.5)
   ```

   You can use `stats` to extract the limits:

   ```
   stats 'long.dat' using (1/$1) name 'A_' nooutput
   plot f_p(x, A_min, A_max)
   ```
3. For fitting, gnuplot uses `1` as starting value for the parameters, if you haven't assigned them an explicit value. And you can imagine, that with `a=1` you're not too close to your values of `1e-7`. For nonlinear fitting, there doesn't exists one unique solution only, for all starting values. So its all about finding the correct starting value and a proper model function.

   With the starting values `a=1e-7; b = 50; k = 1` you get a solution, but the fit isn't very good.

Answer (score 2):

1) you can use the NaN keyword for the missing points: gnuplot will ignore them

2) if what you want to plot is a function, by definition it's defined for every x so it will extend allover

what you might want to do is to store the fitted points on a file, something like:

```
set table "func.txt"
plot [0.5:7.5] f(x)
unset table
```

and then plot the file rather than the function. you might want to use the samples of your datafile to tune the result: type "help samples"

Comment: NaN is great! Thanks bibi!